# Solspace Freeform and sending generated email to recipient from the form

Tags: solspace-freeform, tell-a-friend

Is there any way to send generated email (based on a template) to an address obtained from the form?

I'm looking for something similar to the [tell-a-friend](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#tellafriend_form) functionality but instead sending an email with a link I want to send generated HTML message based on a content from the landing page to email address from the form.

Also how can I get an email address sent from to be an email from the form (as your email in an example from a link above)?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a field in your form to hold an email address, let's call it `email`. Make sure you have a Freeform field in the CP called `email` and linked to your form. You need this field to "catch"/save that information to the database, to then be used in your notification email.

Then, in your notification template, you can use `{email}` where you need it: the "From Email" setting, in your notification email body, etc.

As an extra note, notification templates also support EE tags, variables and conditionals, so you can control the content of your email body based on the submitted form content,
eg. `{if favorite_food == "apples"} Content about apples {/if}`